# Deduce member function arguments / return type

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have the following code:

```
template <class... Args>
struct TypeList
{
    static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Args);

    template <std::size_t N>
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};

struct Generator
{
    std::tuple<float, float> process(float, int, size_t)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
};
```

Is there any way to deduce both the tuple template arguments as well as the input arguments for `Generator::process` in order to construct a class that has the following template arguments.

```
struct Node<GenType, ReturnTypesList, ArgumentTypeList>
```

Where `ReturnTypesList` contains template arguments of the returned tuple and `ArgumentTypeList` contains the variadic argument types of the process function. It is assumed that all process functions will return a tuple.

Comment: I've read it multiple times, and I don't understand your question.

Comment: Something like `template <class... ReturnArgs, class... Args> Node<GenType, TypeList<ReturnArgs...>, TypeList<Args...>> magic(std::tuple<ReturnArgs...> (Generator::*arg)(Args...)) {}`?

Comment: Then use `decltype(magic(&Generator::process))`

Comment: Yes! This is indeed the magic I was looking for. How do I upvote your answer and is there also a way to do this without passing any runtime arguments? I can't seem to find how to pass a member function type as template argument.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you are looking for, but probably something like this would work for you:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <class... Args>
struct TypeList
{
    static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Args);

    template <std::size_t N>
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};

struct Generator
{
    std::tuple<float, float> process(float, int, size_t)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
};

template<typename GenType, typename ReturnTypesList, typename ArgumentTypeList>
struct Node {};

template<typename T>
struct S
{
    template<typename... RArgs, typename... Args>
    static auto gen(std::tuple<RArgs...>(T::*)(Args...)) -> Node<T, TypeList<RArgs...>, TypeList<Args...>>;
};

template<typename T>
using NodeType = decltype(S<T>::gen(&T::process));

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<NodeType<Generator>,  Node<Generator, TypeList<float, float>, TypeList<float, int, size_t>>>::value, "!");
}
```

`NodeType` is the required type once specialized with the specific generator, as you can see from the test in the `main`.
In the specific case:

```
Node<Generator, TypeList<float, float>, TypeList<float, int, size_t>>
```

Don't mind if the member is provided as a function parameter instead of a template argument. The whole thing is *solved* at compile-time anyway.

As a side note, the solution won't work for those generators that have overloaded `process`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <tuple>

template <class...>
struct Node;

struct Generator {
  std::tuple<float, float> process(float, int, size_t);
};

template <class... Args1, class ClassType, class... Args2>
auto foo(std::tuple<Args1...> (ClassType::*)(Args2...)) -> Node<ClassType, Args1..., Args2...>;



int main() {

  // T is Node<Generator, float, float, float, int, size_t>
  using T = decltype(foo(&Generator::process));

  return 0;
}
```

`Args1` and `Args2` are deduced properly because the pack expansion that appears at the very end of the template parameter list will be deduced. And the member function pointer which is passed to `foo` contains all the types necessary. All the template parameters of `foo` will be deduced separately and then combined to a type which match the type of `&Generator::process` after certain adjustment. [Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

Unrelated: If process isn't garanted to return a `std::tuple`, we can still use a template template parameter, aka `template <class...> class TT`

### Edit according to the information provided by @Martin Bonner

```
template <class...>
struct Node {};

template <class...>
struct TypeList {};

struct Generator {
  std::tuple<float, float> process(float, int, size_t) {}
};

template <class... ReturnArgs, class GeneratorType, class... Args>
auto magic(std::tuple<ReturnArgs...> (GeneratorType::*arg)(Args...))
    -> Node<GeneratorType, TypeList<ReturnArgs...>, TypeList<Args...> > {
  using ReturnType =
      Node<GeneratorType, TypeList<ReturnArgs...>, TypeList<Args...> >;

  return ReturnType{};
}

int main() {
  magic(&Generator::process);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but it's close. Unfortunately in this answer there is no way for me to distinguish between the two type lists since you use a single variadic template to instantiate Node. Martin Bonner gave me the answer I needed. I am still trying to figure out how to pass the member function as a template argument though.